# Windows 10 Normal User Missing Half My RAM

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, user-accounts

My computer is equipped with 8 GB of RAM which are correctly setup and used by my admin user.

The problem is with my normal user acocunt with no privileges. It always shows high memory usage that I don't see when using my admin user.

[image: Memory usage as displayed by Windows 10]

Then I took a look at the users tab to see that only about 4 GB are being using while showing 90+% of usage! What is happening? Why do I have only 4 Gb for my normal user? s

[image: RAM used by users]

Comment: Are you sure that you are reading the numbers right?  All I see is that the work account is using 93.81% of the **used memory**. (Not off all available memory).

Comment: Yeah, but 3549MB+234MB != 7.3GB. I don't know where the remainder of the RAM is used.

Comment: Are you running any VM's and have the additional RAM assigned to them?

Comment: No. When I log into my admin account, most of my 8GB is available to user processes. But when I use my normal account I seem to have only about 4GB.

Comment: I thought that maybe my admin user was using the RAM but the screenshot shows otherwise.

Comment: Could be a memoryleak - or for some reason your PC is storing "cached" files in the RAM for quick access
You could always try to run Memtest (which is free) and see if it lists any issues with your RAM

Comment: open a CMD.exe as admin, run this command **wpr.exe -start ReferenceSet -filemode && timeout -1 && wpr.exe -stop C:\HighMemoryUsage.etl**, wait 10 seconds, press a key to stop logging. Zip the large ETL file (+ NGENPDB folder) into 1 zip, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: have you captured the trace? Otherwise I can't see the cause